# Plotting TimeStamp Data from Excel

Tags: excel

I have data recorded on my excel sheet. This data is actually timestamp.

I would like to plot my recorded time-stamp first image values similar to second following figure.

### [image: recorded time stamps]

### [image: Want to have this format]

---

---

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are trying to do... do you want to create a histogram with the number of events per day (or per hour)?

Comment: Let s imagine that you keep track of user activity.Let's say weather application on mobile application. Whenever user uses the app, timestamp saved into excel and you want to plot this timestamp to see global pictures of when user uses app most.

Comment: Look at updated image above

Comment: Do you want to do this using VBA?

Comment: I am not familiar with VBA. I think that could be possible in excel. But I am not that level of expert

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering to both your question and your comment, you want to build a histogram of the occurrences in time.

You need to define the size of the bin you want. Let's say your bin size is 5 minutes, and you want to plot the histogram for a 24 hours period.

**Doing it by hand**

Create a little table as follows:

```
         A      |  B                |  C
  -----------------------------------------------------
1 |    start    | end               | event_count
2 |    00:00:00 | =A2 + time(0,5,0) | =countIfS(dataSheet!G:G,">=" & A2,dataSheet!G:G,"<" & B2)
3 |    =B2      | =A3 + time(0,5,0) | =countIfS(dataSheet!G:G,">=" & A3,dataSheet!G:G,"<" & B3)
```

Copy the formulas in row 3 as much times as you need. Then create a bar chart.

Notice that the value in the formula written in cells `B2`, `B3`,... is the size of the bin you are specifying.

**Doing it with code**

Since this is a programming Q&A site, a programming solution is expected:

```vb
public sub createMyTimeHistogram(inputRange as Range, binSize as integer)
' Parameters:
'    inputRange: The range that stores the data
'    binSize: The size of the bin (in minutes)

    Dim t as Date
    Dim n as Integer
    Dim outputSheet as String, outputRow as long


    t = timeserial(0,0,0)
    outputSheet = "MyOutputSheet" ' I'll assume this worksheet exists in the current workbook,
                                  ' and it is empty
    With thisWorkbook.Sheets(outputSheet)
        .cells(1,1).value = "Bin"
        .cells(1,2).value = "Count"
    End With
    outputRow = 2
    while t < 1
        n = Excel.WorksheetFunction.CountIfS(inputRange, ">=" & CDbl(t), inputRange, "<" & CDbl(t + timeserial(0,binSize,0)))
        With thisWorkbook.Sheets(outputSheet)
            .cells(outputRow, 1).Value = t
            .cells(outputRow, 2).Value = n
        End With
        t + timeserial(0,binSize,0)
        outputRow = outputRow + 1
    wend
end sub
```